# Android play video for URL Error(100,0)

Tags: java, android

In my app i want play video from URL. most of the device it works fine but nexus 4(kitkat 4.4.4) didn't work fine. error is "Sorry, This video cannot be played" please help me.

```
MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(streamingVideoView);
            mediacontroller.setMediaPlayer(streamingVideoView);
```

[enter link description here][1]
                String videoURL = "xx`dd`xxxx";

```
            Uri video = Uri.parse(videoURL);
            streamingVideoView.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            streamingVideoView.setVideoURI(video);


            streamingVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener () {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    hideProgressDialog();

                    mp.stop();
                    callBack();

                    return false;
                }
            });


}
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. android 4.4.4 support HLS **version 4**. other android version support HLS verso